# Where can I read about elliptic operators on manifolds?

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

In Voisin's beautiful book on Hodge theory she gives a proof that every cohomology class can be represented by a harmonic form by referring to the the following theorem on elliptic operators:

Let $P : E → F \ $  be an elliptic differential operator on a compact
manifold. Assume that $E$ and $F$ are of the same rank, and are equipped with
metrics. Then $\operatorname{ker} P \subset C^{\infty}(E)\ $ is ﬁnite-dimensional, $P( C^{\infty}(E)) \subset C^{\infty}(F) \ $ is closed and of ﬁnite codimension, and we have a decomposition as an orthogonal direct sum (for the $L^2$ metric) $$ C^{\infty}(E) = \operatorname{ker}  P \oplus P^{\ast}( C^{\infty}(F)), $$
which she then applies to the Laplace operator.

Unfortunately, her reference for this ([Demailly - Théorie de Hodge L2 et Théor`emes d'annulation](http://smf4.emath.fr/en/Publications/PanoramasSyntheses/1996/3/pdf/smf_pano-synth_3_3-112.pdf)) is in French, which I don't understand.

I am primarily hoping for a reference on elliptic operators which proves this theorem; however, at the same time I also feel like I should know more about elliptic operators in general, and 'how they can be used in geometry' (can they, actually? I'm thinking about Atiyah-Singer here, which I don't understand at all, so I'm not sure.), so if you can give me a reference about that, it would be much appreciated, too.

Comment: For references for the Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem, see this MO thread: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1162/atiyah-singer-index-theorem

Comment: Concerning elliptic differential operators on manifolds and the Atiyah-Singer theorem, you may be interested in my recent answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/252225/4058

Answer (score 6):

One more suggestion: Wells [Differential Geometry on Complex Manifolds](http://books.google.com/books/about/Differential_analysis_on_complex_manifol.html?id=a4Tptn3EPe4C) has a complete proof, and focuses on the sort of examples which will interest someone who is reading Voisin's book.

Answer (score 5):

The book   *Topology and Analysis: Atiyah-Singer Index Formula and Gauge-theoretic Physics* by Booss and Bleecker (Springer , Universitxt) seems to be exactly what you are loooking for.
It is an introduction to the Atiyah-Singer index formula, with all prerequisites carefully developed :Fredholm operators, (pseudo-)differential operators on manifolds, Sobolev spaces, vector bundles and much more. 
The style is quite friendly, with many examples,remarks, exercises,  interspersed throughout the text.
To sum up, I find the blend of analysis, manifold theory  and topology in this book quite remarkable and unusual.

I am only really familiar with the German original version, written by Booss alone. The English translation I refer to is enriched by about 100 pages due to Bleecker and devoted to applications in mathematical physics: they seem very interesting but I haven't looked at them seriously .

Comment: I took a look on part II, and I'm very impressed. Pictures, explanations, motivation, and interesting comments are everywhere. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, I am not an exert in this area, but I have collected for my purposes some links about that, so I would like to share.

First of all, I would take a look to "[Lectures on pseudodifferential operators](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rbm/Lecture_notes.html)" of Richard Melrose, Chapter 6 is dedicated to ellipticity, where you can try to find some proofs that you are after.

Next, I would refer to the classical source of this subject, the book of R.Melrose "The Atiyah-Patodi-Singer Index Theorem", a copy is generously provided by the author [here](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rbm/book.html).

Another very interesting online resource is Michael E. Taylor's "[Pseudodifferential operators. Four Lectures at MSRI, September 2008](http://www.math.unc.edu/Faculty/met/msripde.pdf)"

And if you want a quick yet brilliant introduction to the topic don't miss out Rafe Mazzeo's presentation "The Atiyah–Singer Index Theorem: What it is and why you should care"

Some additional googling revealed a plenitude of various texts on the topic. For instance, this one: Nigel Higson and John Roe, [Lectures on Operator K-Theory and the Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem](http://folk.uio.no/rognes/higson/Book.pdf)

"Notes on the Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem" by Liviu I. Nicolaescu also deserves a very good mention! (just google it!)

I hope that this will be more than enough to satisfy your curiosity.

EDIT. And I forgot to mention Victor Guillemin's [homepage](http://www-math.mit.edu/~vwg/) where you can find notes on elliptic operators!

Comment: Thank you very much! All these notes look very good. I especially like those on elliptic operators by Professor Guillemin, as they seem to be completely devoted to proving the theorem in my question.